# How to update state in hooks correctly

Tags: reactjs

as I know State in hooks can be changed in two ways.1 `setCount(count - 1)`,
 2 `setCount((prevCount) => prevCount - 1)`,But I don't understand when I need to use 1 and 2 ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setCount(count - 1)` could be used only if it were guaranteed that `setCount` is called synchronously, and `count` reflects current state. This happens almost never because this indicates that state initialization went wrong:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

if (count == 0)
  setCount(count - 1);
```

Otherwise state setter is usually called in callback functions that will access stale state from enclosing scope, which is a common problem for `useState`:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // count === 0 here, even if it was changed since then
    setCount(count - 1)
  }, 1000)
}, []);
```

The use of state updater function guarantees that fresh state is in use. State updates can be batched this way:

```
setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1);
setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1);
```

For the same reason `this.setState` should be used together with state updater instead of `this.state` in class components.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you don't want to do `setCount(count - 1)` as your update value is based on the existing state value.

By using `setCount((prevCount) => prevCount - 1)` you ensure that you are using the latest value of the state whereas the non-function version will, in some instances, use an out-of-date value.

On the other hand, when you don't care about the current value of the state it's fine to use `setCount(7)`.